# how to protect user's uploading files and sync two storage servers when extending storage

Tags: storage

I have a problem with storage as explained below could you please advise me.

I have created a web site that should work like Youtube. In my web site it should SAVE the HUGE number of video files, that are uploaded ON the server , and all the files should be accessible any time that users wish to see them.

We are trying to use two storage servers. The first server as main storage and the second server as MIRROR. We need to make sure that files are saved on first storage server and at the same time the same files are saved on MIRROR server(as storage backup).

Please imagine that the first storage server has 4 TERABYTE hard installed on it and the mirror server( backup server ) has 4 Terabyte hard installed on it.

Question 1-If for any reason the first storage server IS DOWN , the MIRROR server (storage backup) should start to provide service and when the first storage server is back into the service ,THE FIRST STORAGE SERVER SHOULD BE UPDATED WITH THE MIRROR SERVER WITH THE FILES AND DATA THAT WAS UPLOAD ON MIRROR SERVER.

Question 2-When the hard disk on first storage server and the hard disk on mirror server are full (for example %90), we need to turn off the mirror server and add a new empty 4 Terabyte hard (make a total of 8 terabyte storage) on it then we need this mirror server to be back in the service and BE UPDATED WITH FILES from the first storage server ,

at this moment , we need to turn off the first storage server and add a new empty 4 Terabyte hard(make a total of 8 terabyte storage ) on it then we need this first storage server to be back in the service and be updated with files from mirror server .

HOW CAN WE DO THIS TASK ,MAKING SURE THAT BOTH SERVERS ARE EXTENDED THEN UPDATED AND CONTAIN EXACTLY THE SAME FILES ,WITHOUT ANY INTERRUPTIONS FELT BY USERS .

Many thanks